# Compare result to the previous result where after grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F
2       a1      a2      a3      a4      100
2       a1      b2      c3      a4      100 # note
2       b1      b2      b3      b4      100
2       c1      c2      c3      c4      100
1       a1      a2      a3      a4      120
2       a1      b2      c3      a4      150 # note
1       b1      b2      b3      b4      130
1       c1      c2      c3      c4      110
0       a1      a2      a3      a4      80
```

I want to compare the results of F column where the columns `B-E` match based on `A` column like so:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F               diff
2       a1      a2      a3      a4      100             120/100
2       a1      b2      c3      a4      100 # note      150/100
2       b1      b2      b3      b4      100             130/100
2       c1      c2      c3      c4      100             110/100
1       a1      a2      a3      a4      120             80/120
1       a1      b2      c3      a4      150 # note
1       b1      b2      b3      b4      130
1       c1      c2      c3      c4      110
0       a1      a2      a3      a4      80
```

Since the first line has the same values in the first line where `A` is `1` I do `120/100`.

What I've tried:

`df.groupby(['B',' 'C', 'D', 'E'])` - this groups the data, but I don't know how I could apply the logic of calculating the previous value of column `A`. Or maybe there is a simpler way of achieving it.

Comment: I think you can try `df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].shift(-1) / df['F']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df['d'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].shift(-1).div(df['F'])
print (df)
   A   B   C   D   E    F         d
0  2  a1  a2  a3  a4  100  1.200000
1  2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100  1.500000
2  2  b1  b2  b3  b4  100  1.300000
3  2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100  1.100000
4  1  a1  a2  a3  a4  120  0.666667
5  2  a1  b2  c3  a4  150       NaN
6  1  b1  b2  b3  b4  130       NaN
7  1  c1  c2  c3  c4  110       NaN
8  0  a1  a2  a3  a4   80       NaN
```

Comment: and if I wanted to change the division from `120/100` to `100/120` is this line correct: `df['d'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].div(df['F'].shift(-1)`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Do you think divide from right side? `df['d'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].rdiv(df['F'].shift(-1)` - `rdiv` ?

Comment: could you take a look of a follow up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573905/compare-result-to-the-previous-result-where-after-grouping-and-checking-last-com)?