# Compare result to the previous result where after grouping and checking last compared value

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572545/compare-result-to-the-previous-result-where-after-grouping/64572791#64572791).

A bit changed `df` from the last one where one line has one missing `A` value

```
A       B       C       D       E       F               diff
2       a1      a2      a3      a4      100             120/100
2       a1      b2      c3      a4      100             150/100
2       b1      b2      b3      b4      100             130/100
2       c1      c2      c3      c4      100             110/100
2       d1      d2      d3      d4      100 # missing 1 I want to apply it for every other `A` value
1       a1      a2      a3      a4      120             80/120
1       a1      b2      c3      a4      150 
1       b1      b2      b3      b4      130
1       c1      c2      c3      c4      110
0       a1      a2      a3      a4      80  
0       d1      d2      d3      d4      100 # missing 1
```

The last line where `A` is `2` is only present next where `A` is `0` and not `1`. This line does not care if the next line is the next in order, just next:

`df['d'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].shift(-1).div(df['F'])`

How can I modify it to only take account grouped lines if `A` is only lower by `1` and not more.
In reality I am checking difference in days, and I only want to compare the next day, for example, Monday vs Sunday and not Monday vs Saturday since Sunday is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is add missing values per groups and then processing:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"])['F']
       .unstack()
       .stack(dropna=False)
       .reset_index(name='F')
       .sort_values('A', ascending=False, ignore_index=True))

df1['d'] = df1.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].shift(-1).div(df1['F'])
print (df1)
     B   C   D   E  A      F         d
0   a1  a2  a3  a4  2  100.0  1.200000
1   a1  b2  c3  a4  2  100.0  1.500000
2   b1  b2  b3  b4  2  100.0  1.300000
3   c1  c2  c3  c4  2  100.0  1.100000
4   d1  d2  d3  d4  2  100.0       NaN
5   a1  a2  a3  a4  1  120.0  0.666667
6   a1  b2  c3  a4  1  150.0       NaN
7   b1  b2  b3  b4  1  130.0       NaN
8   c1  c2  c3  c4  1  110.0       NaN
9   d1  d2  d3  d4  1    NaN       NaN
10  a1  a2  a3  a4  0   80.0       NaN
11  a1  b2  c3  a4  0    NaN       NaN
12  b1  b2  b3  b4  0    NaN       NaN
13  c1  c2  c3  c4  0    NaN       NaN
14  d1  d2  d3  d4  0  100.0       NaN
```

If need same number of rows like original is possible use `merge` with no `no` parameter, so it join by intersection of columns between both df:

```
df = df.merge(df1)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E    F     diff         d
0   2  a1  a2  a3  a4  100  120/100  1.200000
1   2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100  150/100  1.500000
2   2  b1  b2  b3  b4  100  130/100  1.300000
3   2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100  110/100  1.100000
4   2  d1  d2  d3  d4  100      NaN       NaN
5   1  a1  a2  a3  a4  120   80/120  0.666667
6   1  a1  b2  c3  a4  150      NaN       NaN
7   1  b1  b2  b3  b4  130      NaN       NaN
8   1  c1  c2  c3  c4  110      NaN       NaN
9   0  a1  a2  a3  a4   80      NaN       NaN
10  0  d1  d2  d3  d4  100      NaN       NaN
```

EDIT: Solution if duplicated groups:

```
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E    F
0   2  a1  a2  a3  a4  100
1   2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100
2   2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100
3   2  b1  b2  b3  b4  100
4   2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100
5   2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100
6   2  d1  d2  d3  d4  100
7   1  a1  a2  a3  a4  120
8   1  a1  b2  c3  a4  150
9   1  b1  b2  b3  b4  130
10  1  c1  c2  c3  c4  110
11  0  a1  a2  a3  a4   80
12  0  d1  d2  d3  d4  100
```

---

```
print (df[df.duplicated(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"], keep=False)])
   A   B   C   D   E    F
1  2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100
2  2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100
4  2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100
5  2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100

df['g'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"]).cumcount()
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E    F  g
0   2  a1  a2  a3  a4  100  0
1   2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100  0
2   2  a1  b2  c3  a4  100  1
3   2  b1  b2  b3  b4  100  0
4   2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100  0
5   2  c1  c2  c3  c4  100  1
6   2  d1  d2  d3  d4  100  0
7   1  a1  a2  a3  a4  120  0
8   1  a1  b2  c3  a4  150  0
9   1  b1  b2  b3  b4  130  0
10  1  c1  c2  c3  c4  110  0
11  0  a1  a2  a3  a4   80  0
12  0  d1  d2  d3  d4  100  0
```

---

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['g','B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"])['F']
       .unstack()
       .stack(dropna=False)
       .reset_index(name='F')
       .sort_values('A', ascending=False, ignore_index=True))

df1['d'] = df1.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E"])['F'].shift(-1).div(df1['F'])
print (df1)

    g   B   C   D   E  A      F         d
0   1  c1  c2  c3  c4  2  100.0  1.000000
1   0  c1  c2  c3  c4  2  100.0       NaN
2   0  a1  a2  a3  a4  2  100.0  1.200000
3   1  a1  b2  c3  a4  2  100.0  1.000000
4   0  a1  b2  c3  a4  2  100.0       NaN
5   0  d1  d2  d3  d4  2  100.0       NaN
6   0  b1  b2  b3  b4  2  100.0  1.300000
7   1  c1  c2  c3  c4  1    NaN       NaN
8   1  a1  b2  c3  a4  1    NaN       NaN
9   0  d1  d2  d3  d4  1    NaN       NaN
10  0  c1  c2  c3  c4  1  110.0       NaN
11  0  a1  a2  a3  a4  1  120.0  0.666667
12  0  b1  b2  b3  b4  1  130.0       NaN
13  0  a1  b2  c3  a4  1  150.0       NaN
14  0  d1  d2  d3  d4  0  100.0       NaN
15  0  c1  c2  c3  c4  0    NaN       NaN
16  1  a1  b2  c3  a4  0    NaN       NaN
17  0  b1  b2  b3  b4  0    NaN       NaN
18  1  c1  c2  c3  c4  0    NaN       NaN
19  0  a1  b2  c3  a4  0    NaN       NaN
20  0  a1  a2  a3  a4  0   80.0       NaN
```

Comment: When trying to unstack I get that `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`, any elegant solution to avoid this?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - It means there are duplicated values of columns `['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"]`, it is expceted?

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates in every column.

Comment: How should be processing dupes? Output should be unique values like if aggregate, e.g. mean like if change `df.set_index(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"])['F']` to `df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"])['F'].mean()` ?

Comment: I think dupes like `print (df[df.duplicated(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"], keep=False)])`

Comment: Well the goal was to divide column `F` by the previous `F` value of column `A`-1 combinations of columns `B-E`, I am not sure how I  deal with the duplicate lines caused by the group by.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - How many rows are returned by `print (df[df.duplicated(['B', 'C', 'D', "E", "A"], keep=False)])` ?

Comment: The len of duplicates is 102394.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Answer was edited, please check if it is what need.